# How to fit a datatable into a panel with percentage max-height

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

[Primefaces 5.0]

I have a tabview that holds a datatable. Depending on the tab, the datatable is filled with different data (i.e. a different number of columns and rows). The following setup handles the data fine, but no matter if I put the max-height constraint on the panel, the tab, or the datatable, it doesn't seem to constrain it to that percent of the screen. If I set the constraint to a particular value (e.g. 300px), it works, but I'd rather not.

**Basically**: I want a datatable that will fit its content up to the point that it takes up 30% of the screen. At this point, it should scroll.

```
    <body style="min-width: 1366px;min-height: 768px;height: 100%;margin-left: 20px;">
    <div style="width: 10%;float: left"> ... </div>
    <div style="width: 90%;float: right">
            <p:panel classStyle="panel" header="Instance Data View" style="width: 100%;max-height: 30%;margin-bottom: 1%">
                <p:tabView value="#{pageBean.tables}" var="table" dynamic="true">
                    <p:tab title="#{table.tableName}" >
                        <p:dataTable var="row" 
                            value="#{pageBean.tableData[table.tableName].data}" 
                            resizableColumns="true">
                            <p:columns value="#{pageBean.tableData[table.tableName].columns}" style="white-space: normal;"
                                var="column" columnIndexVar="columnIndex">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{column}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{row[columnIndex]}"/>
                            </p:columns>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </p:panel>
            ...
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "vh" on the size of max-height, for viewport height like this:

```
<body style="min-width: 1366px;min-height: 768px;height: 100%;margin-left: 20px;">
<div style="width: 10%;float: left"> ... </div>
<div style="width: 90%;float: right">
        <p:panel classStyle="panel" header="Instance Data View" style="width: 100%;margin-bottom: 1%">
            <p:tabView value="#{pageBean.tables}" var="table" dynamic="true">
                <p:tab title="#{table.tableName}" >
                    <p:dataTable var="row" 
                        value="#{pageBean.tableData[table.tableName].data}" 
                        resizableColumns="true" style="max-height: 30vh;">
                        <p:columns value="#{pageBean.tableData[table.tableName].columns}" style="white-space: normal;"
                            var="column" columnIndexVar="columnIndex">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{column}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{row[columnIndex]}"/>
                        </p:columns>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </p:panel>
        ...
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cas use `ScrollWidth` and `ScrollHeight` for datatable. There are three options for this purpose. for example :

```
scrollHeight="30%"
scrollWidth="30%"
scrollable="true"
```

by this method you can control your datatable size.

p.s: you don't say your primefaces version.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I want the datatable to be contained to a particular percentage of the screen - a maximum of 30% of it. However, using the scrollHeight constraint as this day limits it to a percent of the *data*. Since the number of rows I will have isn't set in stone, this doesn't solve my problem.

I added a better description in my question.